# Which date is the expiration date of this Felix cat food?

Tags: cats, cat-food

Felix beef in jelly is my cat's favorite food and she always prefers it to all other types of cat food. Here's an image of the product in question:

[image: Felix Beef in Jelly]

However, she threw up all of her last meal and was very irritated. I suspected that the food must have been bad, so I tried to check the expiration date and that's where this question came up. Please look at the following picture:

[image: One of the Batch of food that I last bought.]

As you can see, there are 3 dates underneath this food pack:

1. 01.2023
2. P: 23.01.2021
3. 01.08.2019

I assume the "P:" designates the production date, however, the existence of a 2019 date, and the fact that my cat threw it all up worries me and makes me wonder if the 2019 is the production date and the 23.01.2021 is the expiry.

So, please help me figure out whether this pack of food is expired or not.
Thank you.

FYI: It has been brought to my attention that my location could be important for answering this question, since laws and regulations might differ in different regions. In that light I should mention that I live in Muscat, Oman.

Comment: I feed my cat Felix Soup and just checked the packaging. It has a similar data "stamp" on it, except mine only has 1 date, which would correspond to "01.2023" (12.2022 on mine) on your packaging. The right side of the stamp with the other two dates isn't included on mine, so I would guess the 01.2023 is the expiration date. Still, that doesn't mean the food is still good. Maybe it wasn't stored properly somewhere between the factory and you. Hope your cat feels better!

Comment: Where do you live? The laws for product information differ between the EU, US and other parts of the world. Knowing your (broad) location would help us in finding the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I live in Muscat, Oman.

Comment: As @HealthCatGuide said, it could be that the package was not stored propperly on the way, or even get a small damage, so air and bacteria could get inside

Comment: No citations, just my common sense: expiration dates are approximate, and the longer the shelf-life is, the less accurate the prediction of expiration date could be; there is no reason to pin the exact day as expiration date of something that has a few years of shelf life, only 01.2023 makes sense as the expiration date in this context. Again, no sources - but I could recall having the impression that pouches of wet cat food tend to have shelf life of 2 years, and cans 3 years, so it would make sense. Still, it is just a number that stops making sense if the package was damaged, etc.

Comment: I tried to find information about expiring date regulations in oman. One of the websites stated, there could be the possibility, that importing companies may underestimate the environments temperatures, when writing at the product "needs no cooling". At the website they wrote about canned beer, but maybe this could be a point for catfood too?

Comment: Important note: The cat throwing up may be *completely unrelated to the expiration date.* You should consult your vet about the vomiting.

Answer (score 1):

According to [koreajoongangdaily.joins.com](https://koreajoongangdaily.joins.com/2008/10/27/etc/What-do-the-dates-on-food-product-labels-mean/2896612.html#:%7E:text=Most%20products%20still%20follow%20the,that%20the%20product%20was%20manufactured):

> Most products still follow the year-month-day order for expiration dates. They may also be labelled “BE” or “BEE,” which stand for “Best Before.” “Consume Before” also refers to the expiration date. “P,” “PRO” or “PRD” stand for the day that the product was manufactured.

The "P" means "production date". However, if your cat threw up, then take her to the vet as soon as possible.

"BE" and "BEE" stand for "best before" and "consume before, respectively; it is the expiration date.

Also, as lila stated in her comment on the question:

> No citations, just my common sense: expiration dates are approximate, and the longer the shelf-life is, the less accurate the prediction of expiration date could be; there is no reason to pin the exact day as expiration date of something that has a few years of shelf life, only 01.2023 makes sense as the expiration date in this context.

In conclusion, 01.2023 is the expiration date - unless the package was damaged (punctured, leaky, or dented to where the lid is partially off), in which case the expiration date is meaningless.

Comment: Downvote with a comment please. I find anyone who downvotes without a comment, someone who is trying to get attention.

Comment: I am sorry and you are right about the downvote without a comment. I voted down because the answer does not contain any convincing reference that "P" means "consume before"; as far as I know expiration date is not shortened as "P", but as "ED" or "EXP" ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expiration_date)). What is more, "P" looks like a reasonable abbreviation of "production" for me, but I have no sources for this.

Comment: I edited it. Added a source.

Comment: Oh okay thank you, now I think I understand this; the source says: _"consume before" also refers to the expiration date_ [full stop there]. _"P", "PRO" or "PRD" stand for the day that the product was manufactured._ and if you miss that there is a full stop ending that sentence, it looks like the sentence lists "P", "PRO" or "PRD" as abbreviations for "consume before". But it does not, please check what do you think and maybe update your answer, because your source itself says that "P" is for production date; thanks.

Comment: I edited it again

Comment: No, it's okay, you are really close to the good answer; if "P" is production date then it's logical that only the date after that (01.2023) could be expiration date. What is more, you could use the reasoning from my comment https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/31144/which-date-is-the-expiration-date-of-this-felix-cat-food#comment41817_31144 to further make the point.